# size problem when i tried to render large dimensions video with AE

Tags: animation, adobe-after-effects

i've been asked to make a 5 sec video for a street advertising screen 4*2 meters (11339 * 5669 pixels)
but that produced a very large file size and i really need to reduce it
when i render as AVI file size was 22 GB!!! and with quicktime it was 3 GB
other AE's codecs resize the video's dimensions or give me settings miss match
so my questions is how can i reduce file size and keep the dimensions and quality?

Comment: Have you seen if this has been asked on [video.se]?

Comment: Have you determined the "virtual pixel size" of the the screen? In many cases the physical makeup of the screen is *not* the desired setup of the files to be displayed on it.

Answer (score 1):

It almost certainly doesn't need to be that big. You're recording detail that no one is going to see unless they have their nose to the screen. Especially with a moving image. In an outdoor ad in particular, they'll be glancing at it as they walk by.

Ask what format the advertiser expects. I wouldn't deliver anything more than 4K (4000px on the longest side), and even that's huge.

As @Confused mentioned, you probably want a more efficient codec, like H.264 for a smaller file size. MPEG Streamclip works, but if you have a recent version of after effects, you  have Adobe Media Encoder, which is fast and works directly from After Effects.

Answer (score 0):

Your Quicktime file, try to export it from MPEG Streamclip with H264, at 50% quality, with these settings:

[image]

MPEG Streamclip is free, and worth a million times that ;)